# A geometry problem involving the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: geometry, lambert-w

For what $x$ value can $W(x)$, $W(2x)$ and $W(3x)$ be the sides of a right triangle where $W$ denotes the Lambert $W$ function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0$ you have $W(3x)> W(2x)> W(x)$, then consider $W(3x)$ the hypotenuse, then you solve:
$$W(x)^2+W(2x)^2=W(3x)^2\;\Rightarrow x\approx 1.36627870097301...$$

Then in reality there would also be complex values ​​if you change the hypotenuse to one of the other 3 values

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to get an exact value?

Comment: @Mr.D You would have to solve the equation $$W(x)^2+W(2x)^2-W(3x)^2=0$$ with some numerical method but you would still end up having to write either a series or an iterated function. In general then the Lambert function has few commonly used constants associated with it, so writing that number in terms of already known values ​​is quite impossible. Mainly because the Lambert function has a more complicated structure than other functions regarding the "nx" terms, so even trying to write everything in terms of $W(x)$ becomes long